# Cannot run Meteor js 1.1 on windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows, meteor

I have tried to install meteor js 1.1 on windows 8.1 with the official installer:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows

But even after restarting my computer, when I type the command `meteor` in the command prompt I get the error `command not found`.

Even after a search on my computer to find the installation folder of meteor, I am unable to find the answer. However, in the add/remove program utility, I can see `meteor.exe`.

As a note, I already successfully installed meteor before, and it used to run smoothly. In the meantime, I have removed and re-installed node, and it seems that since this moment the command `meteor` does not work anymore. Hence my attempt to re-install it.

Does anyone have any idea about how to troubleshoot my issue ?

Comment: does meteor exist in \Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\.meteor

Comment: remove meteor node,and try reinstalling

Comment: whether you were able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved my issue by using the windows command prompt instead of the git bash

It appears that only windows command prompt is supported so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually add Meteor to your Path. 
Go to "Environment variables" (you can find it by doing a simple search in your welcome screen) and add the following entry:

```
C:\\Users\\**your_user_name**\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor
```

Do not forget to separate this entry from other entries by a semicolon ;.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to locate the `.meteor` folder, I do have it, but even in this folder, when I type meteor --version it still cannot find the command.

What I see in the `.meteor` folder is:
- `packages` folder
- `packages-metada` folder
- `meteor.bat` file.

I have already deleted my meteor installation and re-installed it once and still it does not work.

Does my meteor installation looks right ?

Comment: I did not help you to locate the folder, but I advised you to check if the meteor path is in the PATH variable of your operating system (windows 8.1). You can check this by looking at Environment variables parameters and add the Meteor folder to the list if it is not. Doing so will register the meteor command so you can use it in "cmd" terminal.

Comment: You indirectly helped me to locate the meteor installation folder by giving me the PATH to check, thx
I just checked my PATH, and it is correct, but still does not work..

Comment: no worries, thx for your time anyway, will open an issue ticket on their github